# xcode 7 - linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) bitcode

Tags: c++, swift, xcode7, bitcode

Got this problem "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" when trying to build, and i found here many solutions, mostly about changing bitcode in build setting section, but i cant see that option, any other solution? thank you
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: We need to see more of the build log to help you.

Comment: It looks like you have defined a `main` function in both files - "M1.cpp" and "C1.cpp". You can only have one main function in your program.

Comment: thank youu! i'm still learning, eghh...